# Basic Filtering with SSTable

Tags: algorithm, key-value-store

I have data stored as following format in SSTable:

```
<Key, Value>: <Score, {Feature1, Feature2, ...}>
<Key, Value>: <Score, {Feature3, Feature3, ...}>
<Key, Value>: <Score, {Feature2, Feature4, ...}>
```

Basically the score is just a result of pairwise comparison of features. And the score is sorted (because it's the key of SSTable). I'm able to display highest score first with pagination on this format.

However, now the new product requirements is being able to display highest score first with filtering, so if I filter by Feature1, I should only get rows that contains Feature 1

```
<Key, Value>: <Score, {Feature1, Feature2, ...}>
<Key, Value>: <Score, {Feature1, Feature4, ...}>
<Key, Value>: <Score, {Feature1, Feature3, ...}>
```

How can I do so without exhaustingly paginate the list and filter the result that contains Feature1?

Comment: Do you also want to filter with any FeatureN? Are you sure the Score is a unique identifier and not another attribute?

Comment: Do you still want an answer about this?